# Apply match-case to a Spark Column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark 2.0.0 Dataset with a column of `Foo` objects, like this for example `val ds: Dataset[(int, Foo, int)]`.  `Bar` is an extractor of `Foo`.  I'd like to be able to add a column constructed using a match-case statement (or any arbitrarily complex statement really).  Something like this: `ds.withColumn("extracted", $"_2" match { case Bar(x) => x })`.  What is the best way to achieve this behavior in Spark?

**Update:**
@T.Gawęda and @zero323 - Thank you both for your thoughtful comments.  I think my answer lies in this sentence: "it is not possible to patten match over a `Column` to extract data."  I was indeed using a `Dataset[Row]` but I had overly simplified down to a `Dataset[(int, Foo, int)]`.  The reason I was leaning towards using `withColumn` rather than `map` was because (1) I was trying to avoid referencing any of the other columns (they didn't figure into the match-case function) and (2) I wanted to reference the Foo/Bar column by name (as the location of the column in the `Row` was unknown).

Answer (score 4):

If you have statically typed `Dataset` and you want to perform an arbitrary complex operations why not simply use `map`:

```
ds.map { case (first, Bar(x), last) => ??? }
```

`withColumn` is designed to operate on `DataFrames` / `Datasets[Row]` and it is not possible to patten match over a `Column` to extract data.

`Column` is more a function that will applied on a specific dataset than anything else.

Comment: Confirmed, will work. Thanks for explaining what was wrong in my answer :)

Comment: @T.Gawęda My pleasure. If you fix it I'll be happy to up-vote and even delete this one. Regarding UDF you can actually see the problem when you look at the returned type.

Comment: Do not delete this, as you first was right. My pleasure to upvote, that's how community should work :) Even person who is answering can learn something

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `map`, just like in RDD:

```
val dsWithExtracted = ds.map {
    case (x, Bar(y), z) => (x, y, z)
}
```

Edit: withColumn will not work, will return proper type, but will fail in runtime

Comment: This won't work. UDF will get SQL type not `Bar`. `map` will work of course.

Comment: @zero323 test my example, I have run it and it works. Have i missed anything?

Comment: One thing, try to execute this :) (`show`, `first`). There is type safety here so it will simply fail on runtime.

Comment: Well, I forgot about running action, you're right! Sorry!

Comment: You could actually make `udf` work but you'd have to pattern match over SQL types. So for `case class Bar(x: Int)` you could `udf((row: Row) => row match { case Row(x: Int) => ???  })`